File Hash Lookup API doesn't work with Zip files
We're using this Sophos Labs Intellix API - File Hash Lookup API to detect any malicious file to be uploaded in our Salesforce org. However, upon testing, we figured that a zip file that contains a malicious file (ex: eicar.zip) was not detected and returned a reputation score of 30.
Does this API supports zip file scanning? How to resolve the issue with the zip file?
Zip file with a malicious file should be detected.

File hash lookup only provides information about the requested hash. If you provide the hash of a zip file it might be unknown by the service even if the compressed file itself is known. Static file analysis can unzip the file and analyze its content too. You can even provide password if the archive is protected.
